# saving operators in arrays, error

Tags: java, arrays, operators

To give an idea of what I want elaborate with this code is the following:

1. Enter two numbers: 10 7
2. Choose Operator: e.g. (+, - , * and /)
3. What's 10 * 7?
4. Correct!

   ```
   int[] arr = new int[5];


   System.out.println("enter two numbers: ");
   arr[1] = sc.nextInt();
   arr[2] = sc.nextInt();


   System.out.println("Choose Operator: ");
   arr[3] = sc.nextInt();


   int operator = arr[1]+arr[3]+arr[2];


   System.out.print("what's "+operator);
   int svar = sc.nextInt();


   if (svar == operator)
       System.out.println("Correct!");
   else
       System.out.println("Wrong - the right answer is "+operator);
   ```

Now I'm having a problem with running some aspects within this code. It works fine to compile but each time the program asks for to "**choose operator**" the compiler responses with the following *error*:

- Exception in thread "main"

  - java.util.InputMismatchException   at
  - java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown
  - Source)    at
  - java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown
  - Source)    at
  - java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown
  - Source)    at
  - java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown
  - Source)
  - at test1.main(test1.java:13)

I wonder how I'm going to deal with this one. But the goal would be to "save" the desired operator, and then put it together with arr[1] and arr[2] (shown in **int operator**) to "sort of" create this whole mathematical operation. *But the error occurs when I choose one particular operator.*

I would appreciate some help with this one. Thank you!

Comment: You are trying to read a character with sc.nextInt(). That doesn't sound right.

Comment: What do you think the line `System.out.print("what's "+operator)` prints?

Comment: number, operator, number. For an example: 10 * 10

Comment: I think you should go and learn what types are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you are trying to use `int`s and `String`s interchangeably, which is not possible in a strongly-typed language such as Java.

Secondly, for this kind of calculator application you should be using a stack. For easiest implementation, have one stack for numbers and one stack for operators.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `nextInt`, which tries to read an integer.
Since you aren't entering an integer, you're getting an error.

To implement your idea, you would need an `Operator` interface with an `int execute(int x, iny y)` method, and a separate class for each operator.
You would then read a character from `sc` and find the corresponding `Operator` implementation for that character.  (perhaps using a `Map<String, Operator>`)

Comment: These days you probably want to use `java.util.function.BinaryOperator` et al. if you're going to be doing this in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
System.out.println("Choose Operator: ");
    arr[3] = sc.nextInt();
```

you are trying to store a '+' operator as an int, maybe you should read a line and then determine what to do with the read in input.

Comment: ok, I tried nextLine but it says that it cannot convert a String to int. So that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is two Ints, one Char and one Double, if it's not a must to use arrays so this is the code for you:

```
int num1, num2;
double result;
char op;

System.out.println("enter two numbers: ");
num1 = sc.nextInt();
num2 = sc.nextInt();

System.out.println("Choose Operator: ");
op = System.in.read();  // Edited

switch ( op )
{
     case '+': res = num1 + num2; break;
     case '-': res = num1 - num2; break;         
     case '/': res = num1 / num2; break;
     case '*': res = num1 * num2; break;
}    

System.out.print("what's " + num1 + op + num2 );

if ( sc.nextInt() == res )
    System.out.println("Correct!");
else
    System.out.println("Wrong - the right answer is " + res );
```

Enjoy,
Rotem

Comment: Hi! Thanks alot. Although I'm not sure about the statement about "op = sc.nextChar". Eclipse has no idea what it is, and it want's to change it to nextInt();

Comment: Ohh Eclipse is right =) It should be " op = sc.nextLine() " , there is no nextChar method (I just read the Scanner API - http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html ) Now it's all good ! B.T.W it is also possible using System.in.read() to get a single char..